# Java function Else issue

Tags: java, function, if-statement

Sooo I'm having an issue with my function.

```
static int syracuse(int x){
    if (x%2==0){
      return x/2;
    else{
      return 3*x+1;
    }
   }
  }
```

Well soo my issue is : if x is even, return x/2   OR  is x if odd. returns 3x+1.  But when I try to compile java tells me that ( 'else' with 'if')   I don't know what to do :\

why would I need a else if?

Comment: Use an IDE like Eclipe. Makes it much easier to spot mismatched braces.

Comment: If you're calling this a lot you may want to do an ANDing operation for a huge performance increase.

Comment: @Thilo, `if (x & 0x01) { return 3*x+1; } else { return x/2; }` should be a lot faster.

Comment: @John: In order for that to compile, it needs to be ` if ((x & 0x01) == 1)` and running both versions of the method in a tight loop for integers from 1 to 1000000 shows no speed difference.

Comment: @Thilo im not a java programmer, but it was just an example of logic. By "a lot" I meant if he's calling it tens of millions of times doing mathematical equations. 1 million isn't a lot. Try 50 million iterations. I've done it in Perl, the results will probably be significantly different in Java: http://pastebin.ca/1789758 . Keep in mind, the time utility isn't the most accurate thing out there, but it's a decent indicator for basics like this.

Comment: @John T: Java's JIT does that sort of micro-optimizations for you over time and it does them well, there's usually no need to do them unless you're 100% sure that some specific mechanic in Java prevents JIT from doing its job.

Comment: It isn't really "micro" if you're doing millions of calculations

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your problem is mismatched braces:

```
static int syracuse(int x){
    if (x%2==0){
      return x/2;
    } else {
      return 3*x+1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your braces are wrongly placed.

```
static int syracuse(int x){
    if (x%2==0){
      return x/2;
    }
    else{
      return 3*x+1;
    }
}
```

PS: I'm not an java expert, so I'm not sure x/2 can be cast as int on return

Answer (score 2):

```
if (x%2==0){
      return x/2;
```

change to:

```
if (x%2==0){
      return x/2;
}
```